# Add current date/time to default filename

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm using `psychopy` with `iohub` to run an eye tracking experiment (SR Eyelink tracker).

**Problem**: The edf output that is being saved on the display machine is called "et.data" and if I run the experiment multiple times, the file just keeps being rewritten.  What I would like is for the edf files to be saved with a date/time stamp, so they don't get rewritten.

**Filename source**: I noticed that the source of the filename is in the `iohub_config.yaml` file, stated as `default_native_data_file_name: et_data`, which it gets from a .py file in the package attached below.

How can I edit this so that `default_native_data_file_name` gives current date/time (eg: `20160812114506`)?

## native data recording file

```
        default_native_data_file_name=tracker_config.get('default_native_data_file_name',None)
        if default_native_data_file_name:
            if isinstance(default_native_data_file_name,(str,unicode)):
                r=default_native_data_file_name.rfind('.')
                if default_native_data_file_name>0:
                    if default_native_data_file_name[r:] == 'edf'.lower():
                        default_native_data_file_name=default_native_data_file_name[:r]

                if len(default_native_data_file_name)>7:
                    EyeTracker._full_edf_name=default_native_data_file_name
                    twoDigitRand=np.random.randint(10,99)
                    EyeTracker._host_edf_name=self._full_edf_name[:3]+twoDigitRand+self._full_edf_name[5:7]
                else:
                    EyeTracker._full_edf_name=default_native_data_file_name
                    EyeTracker._host_edf_name=default_native_data_file_name
            else:
                print2err("ERROR: default_native_data_file_name must be a string or unicode value")

        if self._local_edf_dir and self._full_edf_name:
            EyeTracker._active_edf_file=self._full_edf_name+'.EDF'    
        self._eyelink.openDataFile(self._host_edf_name+'.EDF')
```

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: But this isn't Python. Is this part of your Psychopy `.py` file?

Comment: I think I've just found the python source for file naming, updated code in edit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want the variable `default_native_data_file_name` to be a string representing the current date and time.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt_now = datetime.now()
default_native_data_file_name = dt_now("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
print default_native_data_file_name
```

N.B. this is python2.

Comment: @pyne, you would replace `default_native_data_file_name=tracker_config.get('default_native_data_file_name',None)` in your code with  `default_native_data_file_name = dt_now("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` from @Sci-Prog. Import `datetime` somewhere at the top of your file, and you can get the current time with `datetime.now()` anywhere.

Comment: thanks @Sci Prog and @Jakub, but I keep getting `TypeError("'datetime.datetime' object is not callable` and I cannot work out why.

Comment: What is confusing is that the module is called `datetime` and the class is **also** called `datetime`.  If you use `import datetime`, then the **module** is in your namespace, so you must use `n = datetime.datetime.now()`.  On the other hand, if you use `from datetime import datetime`, then the **class** is in your namespace, so you must use `n = datetime.now()`.  Suggestion: consult python documentation for more help.